# Latitude Longtitude to X, Y coordinate system using python

Tags: latitude-longitude, utm, pyproj

I am really new to this stuff and I have to do something for work. I am using python pyproj library to convert lat, long values to x, y coordinates.

```py
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=34 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

and tried the following command myProj(50.061665, 19.937332).

Why do I need to specify zone when I create myProj, because the zone should be determinable based on lat long values?

Answer (score 2):

You need the zone, because one geographical coordinate can be calculated in many zones. I agree, that the coordinate determines a certain zone, but - for example - near to the border between two zones you may want all your points in the same coordinate system. Or your extent is bigger than the "cover" of one zone, then you too want uniform coordinate values.